# SoundTouch C++ API to change tempo of sound in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, audio, soundtouch

How to use soundtouch C++ API to change tempo of sound file in Linux?

I have to perform following command line functionality with SoundTouch C++ library.

```
soundstretch in.wav out.wav -tempo=30
```